# linking databases for reporting

Tags: database-design, sql-server-express, database-link

I am attempting to design a simple reporting feature for some financial market data.

I have a few sets of data, and I am trying to figure out what will be the best way to organize the tables, in particular for reporting.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Express, which I am comfortable with for simple tasks and I've designed a few reports.

I have one table with `Trade` data, which is basically a log, with `Trade #`, `Entry Date`, `Entry Price`, `Exit Date`, `Profit` and some other information. Simple and easy.

I want to link each trade entry with some data specific to that entry. For example, in my Trade Table, I might have 200 entries. Each entry, however has pricing data from before and after the trade date that I would like to get.

I want to produce a report that lists the trade data, adjusted for parameters which I can do.  The report could display a graph to show trade specific data that is more detailed than can just be fit in columns from the current record.

Any ideas or references to check out would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the option of moving the data into another database I would begin looking at using a star schema.  Here is a website that might help you begin research

http://www.ciobriefings.com/Publications/WhitePapers/DesigningtheStarSchemaDatabase/tabid/101/Default.aspx

Star schemas are built specificly for the fast retrieval of large amounts of data and are very good at aggregating that data over time.  Plus having the data seperated from your OLTP database means that there are not as many draw backs to adding indexes.  What's more having your data layed out in a Star Schema sets you up to be for creating data cubes with SSAS in the future; although, you do not need a cube to interface with the data.